# My ExtJS store AJAX or Rest calls are not working despite working in Curl, Angular, and jQuery

Tags: rest, extjs

This is my store:

```
Ext.define('testApp.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'testApp.model.User',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://jsonstub.com/blogPost',
    headers: {
        'JsonStub-User-Key': '[redacted]',
        'JsonStub-Project-Key': '[redacted]'
    },
    afterRequest: function(req, res) {
        console.log("Ahoy!", req.operation.response);    
    }
},
```

});

When my application runs I get a:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://jsonstub.com/blogPost?_dc=1392922205820&page=1&start=0&limit=25
```

I thought it was my authentication, but if I enter the wrong header values I get a 403 error instead of the 404 error.

Comment: What does your j Query code look like?

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://jsonstub.com/blogPost',
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader('JsonStub-User-Key', 'c475ddb9-7207-4dd4-8e22-23a828f1d4b3');
        request.setRequestHeader('JsonStub-Project-Key', 'ab319e35-e04e-4d9e-989c-71d51977923c');
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    //do something with data
});

This works perfectly though.

Comment: Is the store's request sending a GET?

Comment: Yes it is, I don't know why I get the 404, I get the object back when I don't use ExtJs just fine.

Comment: I'm guessing an issue with headers then?